# Showing that the functions $\sin(2n+1)x$ are orthogonal with respect to the inner product $\int_0^{\pi/2}f(x)g(x)dx$

Tags: fourier-series, orthogonal-polynomials

I couldn't find this anywhere here, so I'll ask it.

> How would I show: $$\{\;\sin((2n+1)x)\;\}$$ on $[0,\pi/2]$, where $n>0$ and is an integer, is an orthogonal set with respect to the inner product $\int_0^{\pi/2}f(x) g(x) dx$?

I've tried a couple different ways, and they all explode into crazy integrals. Is there a clean way to show this?

Comment: If you don't give out the linear space and the inner product defined on it, how is it possible to know whether any set is orthogonal or not?!

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry! The interval is [0,pi/2] and the inner product is the integral on that interval of the product of the two functions. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might not seem to be the case, the integrals you presumably wrote down actually can be evaluated by elementary (if clever) means. [This note](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/mathdl/CMJ/Nicol158-160.pdf) illustrates two ways of doing so: one using trigonometric identities to change the product $\sin(2n+1)x \cdot \sin(2m+1)x$ into a more easily integrated form, and a second using repeated integration by parts.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that for odd $\;k,\,m\;$ , we have (using trigonometric identities for products):

$$\langle \sin kx,\,\sin mx\rangle=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin kx\sin mx\,\mathrm dx=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\cos(k-m)x-\cos(k+m)x\right)\,dx=$$

$$=\begin{cases}\frac12\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\left(1-\cos2kx\right)\,dx=\frac12\left(\frac\pi2\right)-\left.\frac1{2k}\sin2kx\right|_0^{\pi/2}=\frac\pi4\,,&k=m\\{}\\
\frac12\left.\left(\frac1{k-m}\sin(k-m)x-\frac1{k+m}\sin(k+m)x\right)\right|_0^{\pi/2}=0\,,&k\neq m\end{cases}$$

Thus, multiplying each element of that set by $\;\cfrac4\pi\;$ you get in fact an **orthonormal** basis.

Comment: The interval is 0 to pi/2 not pi. Helps either way thanks

Comment: I ended up working it out myself much the same way, thanks so much!

Comment: @ShaneMurphy Corrected. It still is basically the same.